# Raspberry Pi Catkin make

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rasbperrypi, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm trying to build my workspace with only hector_slam package inside in my new raspberry pi 3 with this http://www.german-robot.com/2016/05/26/raspberry-pi-sd-card-image/ OS (suggested by the ROS team) but every time I do `catkin_make` it freezes in differents %.
Here you have the commands I already tried.

`catkin_make`
`catkin_make -j1`
`catkin_make_isolated`

May be one of you can help me trying to build this workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273975/raspberry-pi-catkin-make/) by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-24**:
Building on the Raspberry Pi can take hours or days for complex software like hector_slam. How long are you waiting for `catkin_make` to finish? Is there any CPU activity while it seems stuck?

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2017-10-24**:
not waiting too match. But it freezes everthig, I can't even move the mouse. Are you telling me I should wait longer?
I opened just one terminal with this command. Tried to echo 3 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches but I get permission denied.

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-10-24**:
I've had a lot of success by adding additional 1gb swap space and ssh'ing into the pi rather than using the GUI. I run "catkin_make -j1", compilation typically takes 2-3 minutes.
Are you building from source? Hector-Slam should be available as an installable package for 16.04.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2017-10-24**:
It has been compiling for an hour. May be I'll try to disable GUI and do what you are telling me to do.
I did not found it as a installable package

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-10-24**:
Hmm, it may be worth checking your package configuration. If I run "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-slam", I am able to install the hector-slam metapackaged including all its related packages. If you're able to install via apt-get you can skip compilation issues.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2017-10-24**:
I would be very upset if this is my answer

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-07**:
What OS is running on the Pi? If Raspbian, you'll need to compile from source. Ubuntu MATE will allow you to install hector-slam from pre-built binaries.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-01-17**:
I'm resuming this work. I saw (this)[https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html] which are stable version for raspberry pi made by someone aka ubiquityrobotics. So these might be more stable when running ros rather than  the raspbian. Ty anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

change catkin_make to catkin_make -j2 to avoid the pi freezing.

---

Originally posted by [Navlesh Gavhale](https://answers.ros.org/users/39017/navlesh-gavhale/) with karma: 16 on 2018-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0